# How do I read from a text file a number of sequential strings and assign each of them to a variable that is an array in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, arrays, readfile

In other languages, I would write code similar to the following to achieve this:

## Define a variable as an array :

Any help with this simple matter would be appreciated. I know that there is
"import array" I could use, but I need help with some example code to help me get jump started.

Thank you all a head of time.

myfile.txt: (there will likely be over 1,000,000 rows in a production environment. These are junk rows for testing.)

```
========================================================================
"0x28ce2ae","This is a forth test","filesys","06/03/2023"
"0x232d37d2","fskjg k jmlsj m lm","select","06/10/2023"
"0x2f79d6f8","oskjfjommmskol","full","06/02/2022"
"0x2f775822","this is a testtesttest","select","01/04/20023"
"0xca21103","nosomgfmosfmjki","filesys","05/05/20023"
"0x13ec8751","fhgghhhfgfhghggfhfhfhhhhhffhh","recovery","06/07/2023"
"0X1ADB4922","test","full","06/24/2023"
"0X262B2A15","Just stuff","filesys","06/27/2023"
"0X49CB95E4EDBE","test large test","recovery","06/27/2023"
"0X39CDECD2CFD5","this is a test of stupidity","select","06/28/2023"

========================================================================


usbNum=[]
shortDescription = []
backupType = []
dateTaken = []

file = open("myfile.txt","r")

print()

#Repeat for each USB backup in the text file.

for line in file:
       
    #Let's split the line into an array called "fields" using the "\",\"" as a separator:

    fields = line.split("\",\"")

    #and let's extract the data:
    
    usbNum = fields[0].replace('"','').upper()
    shortDescription = fields[1]
    backupType = fields[2]
    dateTaken = fields[3].replace('"','')

    # Display the data to the terminal.

    print( usbNum + " taken " + dateTaken + " for " + backupType + ".")

file.close()

====================================================================================
```

Comment: Do you really need to have all those parallel lists? Each line in your file represents a thing (a USB backup, I guess), so wouldn't it be better to have a single list of those? You could use a data class, or a dictionary at least to represent a USB backup.

Comment: Or a list of tuples. So we could define `entries = []` once and in the loop we have `entries.append((usb_num, short_description, backup_type, date_taken))` (I adjusted the variable names according to the Style Guide for Python Code).

Comment: To maybe explain a bit differently: the code you have now says, "I have a list of USB numbers, another list of descriptions, another list of types, ...". That likely isn't how you think about the data - more likely, you think, "I have a list of backups and each has a USB number, a description, a type, ...". So express it that way.

Comment: The problem for me with using a tuple to represent each row is that to access a piece of data inside there (say the description), I have to use an index (1 in this case). That isn't as meaningful as using a name like `"short_description"`. So, I prefer to use names as it makes code easier to read and understand.

Comment: Use a dictionary as the list content. `entry = {'usbNum': usb_num, 'shortDescription': short_description, ...}` followed by `entries.append(entry)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this could work:

```
usbNum = []
shortDescription = []
backupType = []
dateTaken = []

with open(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\1.txt", "r") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        fields: list[str] = line.split(",")
        usbNum.append(fields[0].strip("\"").upper())
        shortDescription.append(fields[1].strip("\""))
        backupType.append(fields[2].strip("\""))
        dateTaken.append(fields[3].strip("\"").strip("\n"))

print(usbNum, shortDescription, backupType, dateTaken)
```

---

Thanks for Matthias's comment, I did some optimization:

```
import csv

with open(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\1.txt", "r") as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    # by the way, I agree here a dict might be better if the usbNum is unique...
    backups = {row[0].upper(): {"shortDescription": row[1], "backupType": row[2], "dateTaken": row[3]} for row in rows}  # usbNum: {shortDescription: xxx, backupType: xxx, dateTaken: xxx}

print(backups)
```

Comment: That technically answers the question, but the approach with the different lists is suboptimal. And why do you use `f.seek(0)`? The file pointer is at the beginning of the file anyway. If you really want to optimize the code, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much! I have a solution now and considered this closed now. I have implemented the solution provided by Matthias. I learned so much. Coming from a purely C environment, Python doesn't always make sense. LOL!

This is the solution:

```
usbNum = []
shortDescription = []
backupType = []
dateTaken = []


with open(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\1.txt", "r") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        fields: list[str] = line.split(",")
        usbNum.append(fields[0].strip("\"").upper())
        shortDescription.append(fields[1].strip("\""))
        backupType.append(fields[2].strip("\""))
        dateTaken.append(fields[3].strip("\"").strip("\n"))
```

Comment: You might want to accept @hrungnir's answer as the solution in that case, instead of reposting his solution. Thanks!